# Self-Hosted Web API 2 (OWIN) & SSL 3 POODLE?

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, owin, poodle-attack

Was just wondering if self-hosted WebAPI applications are affected by the POODLE attack.  We are using netsh to configure SSLCERT with our Web API 2 applications.  Is there a way to disable SSLv3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please see “Disable SSL 3.0 in Windows” here: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/3009008

Source: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/571293